# Openpyxl too slow for deleting empty rows and shift them up Microsoft Excel

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

So I had multiple empty rows in my Microsoft Excel data, therefore, I wanted to delete them using Python. However, in the process of doing so, it's too slow the data itself is only 80MB. This is my code:

```
import openpyxl 

file_path = 'C:\\Users\\ASUS\\Downloads\\Priority List Expiry Gathering-Drugs & Consumables Oct 2023 (3) (1) copy.xlsx'

# Load the workbook using openpyxl 
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path) 
sheet = workbook['Sheet1']

empty_rows = [] for row in sheet.iter_rows(max_col=50):
    empty = not any(cell.value for cell in row)
    if empty:
        empty_rows.append(row[0].row)  # Append the row number

# Delete empty rows using openpyxl 
for row_idx in reversed(empty_rows):
    sheet.delete_rows(row_idx, 1)
```

is there any way to speed up this process? because I need it for data cleansing of my work

Comment: Deleting from the bottom of the worksheet is fastest.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your code is slow but making two loops might slow things a bit.
Perform the empty check and delete in the one loop should speed it somewhat.

```
import openpyxl

file_path = 'C:\\Users\\ASUS\\Downloads\\Priority List Expiry Gathering-Drugs & Consumables Oct 2023 (3) (1) copy.xlsx'

# Load the workbook using openpyxl
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)
sheet = workbook['Sheet1']

rows = reversed(list(sheet.iter_rows(max_row=50)))
for row in rows:
    if not any(cell.value for cell in row):
        sheet.delete_rows(row[0].row, 1)

workbook.save('deleted.xlsx')
```